# Radio button won't select on 2nd view

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have many pieces to my code.

The issue I am having is that I have a select which displays option available. Based on the chosen option a `div` will hide or show containing radio buttons that correspond to sizes available for that option. Some are available and others are not. All of the values are retrieved from a database with PHP. The select works fine and and the radio buttons hide and show as expected. The in/out of stock radio buttons display fine. However, on the first set I can select the size and on the 2<sup>nd</sup> set I cannot. Any ideas?

I have Javascript and jQuery on page, not sure if there is a conflict. I just don't know what else to try. Basically the page loads with the default radio buttons and then based on the selection the radio buttons change. As I said everything works as I expect it to except I cannot select a radio button inside the `div` with `id="74"`. `"74-EE"` works fine.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu2f7jtd/)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="M3105" />
<div class=styled-select>
  <select name="options" id="select" onChange="handleSelection(value) ">
    <option value="DEFAULT" selected>Select option to see available sizes<img src="images/turqarrow.png" width="10" height="10" ></option>
    <option value="74-EE">Option 1:   Toe:7 Heel:4 Width:EE</option>
    <option value="74">Option 2:   Toe:7 Heel:4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br><h3><b>Choose a Size:</b><h3>
<div class="hide" id="74-EE">
  <div class=radio_button>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="6" id="6" /><label for="6" class="out-stock" >6</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="6.5" id="6.5" /><label for="6.5" class="out-stock" >6.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="7" id="7" /><label for="7" class="out-stock" >7</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="7.5" id="7.5" /><label for="7.5" class="out-stock" >7.5</label>                
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="8" id="8" /><label for="8" class="out-stock" >8</label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="8.5" id="8.5" /><label for="8.5" class="in-stock" >8.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="9" id="9" /><label for="9" class="out-stock" >9</label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="9.5" id="9.5" /><label for="9.5" class="in-stock" >9.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="10" id="10" /><label for="10" class="out-stock" >10</label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="10.5" id="10.5" /><label for="10.5" class="in-stock" >10.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11" id="11" /><label for="11" class="out-stock" >11</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11.5" id="11.5" /><label for="11.5" class="out-stock" >11.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="12" id="12" /><label for="12" class="out-stock" >12</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hide" id="74">
  <div class=radio_button><input type="radio" name="size" value="6" id="6" /><label for="6" class="in-stock" >6</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="6.5" id="6.5" /><label for="6.5" class="out-stock" >6.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="7" id="7" /><label for="7" class="out-stock" >7</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="7.5" id="7.5" /><label for="7.5" class="out-stock" >7.5</label>        
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="8" id="8" /><label for="8" class="out-stock" >8</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="8.5" id="8.5" /><label for="8.5" class="out-stock" >8.5</label>    
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="9" id="9" /><label for="9" class="out-stock" >9</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="9.5" id="9.5" /><label for="9.5" class="out-stock" >9.5</label>    
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="10" id="10" /><label for="10" class="out-stock" >10</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="10.5" id="10.5" /><label for="10.5" class="out-stock" >10.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11" id="11" /><label for="11" class="out-stock" >11</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11.5" id="11.5" /><label for="11.5" class="out-stock" >11.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="12" id="12" /><label for="12" class="out-stock" >12</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hide" id="DEFAULT">
  <div class=radio_button><input type="radio" disabled name="2size" value="7" id="7" /><label for="7" class="out-stock" >7</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="7.5" id="7.5" /><label for="7.5" class="out-stock" >7.5</label>    
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="8" id="8" /><label for="8" class="out-stock" >8</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="8.5" id="8.5" /><label for="8.5" class="out-stock" >8.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="9" id="9" /><label for="9" class="out-stock" >9</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="9.5" id="9.5" /><label for="9.5" class="out-stock" >9.5</label>    
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="10" id="10" /><label for="10" class="out-stock" >10</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="10.5" id="10.5" /><label for="10.5" class="out-stock" >10.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11" id="11" /><label for="11" class="out-stock" >11</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="11.5" id="11.5" /><label for="11.5" class="out-stock" >11.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="12" id="12" /><label for="12" class="out-stock" >12</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="12.5" id="12.5" /><label for="12.5" class="out-stock" >12.5</label>
    <input type="radio" disabled name="size" value="13" id="13" /><label for="13" class="out-stock" >13</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
  <input type="submit" value="Contact to Order" class="submit" />
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function handleSelection(choice) {

  if (choice == '74') {
    document.getElementById('74-EE').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('DEFAULT').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(choice).style.display = "block";
  } else if (choice == '74-EE') {
    document.getElementById('74').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('DEFAULT').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(choice).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('74').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('74-EE').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('DEFAULT').style.display = "block";
  }
}
window.onload = handleSelection("DEFAULT");
```

#### CSS:

```
.radio_button input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #272014;
}
.in-stock {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #04AAB0;
}
.out-stock {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: grey;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.styled-select select {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #04AAB0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 35px;
}
.styled-select {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `id`s should be unique. You can't repeat them. Use `class`es instead.

Comment: And for compatibility, IDs shouldn't start with numbers.

Comment: The ids of the radio buttons are unique. I tried changing the name so the are like size1, size2, etc. but that didn't work.

Comment: I can try changing the IDs but I don't think that would do it. If the Ids were an issue I don't think any of it would work.\

Comment: Changing the Ids doesn't work. Can you post an example of what you mean by using classes?

Comment: One other note. If I get rid of display: none; in the radio_button style, the circles appear and it works as intended. However, I don't want the radio button circles.

Comment: Ok I got it working. I displayed all the sets and saw that when I clicked on the second, the first was highlighted. Then I realized what was meant by the ids. The radio button ids were named the same. I caned the names and it worked. Thanks!